# (SFML)Player constructor not updating with correct animation when key is pressed

Tags: c++, animation, constructor, 2d, sfml

My sprite moves to the left, right, up and down when the correct corresponding key is pressed but only the row 0 animation is used, but for some odd reason when I press two keys at the same time like (W,A) or (S, D) is transfer to opposite animation to which side it is moving. I tried moving the if statements directing the animation update to a nested if statement inside the key press if statements and that did nothing good, I then tried just having it update based off the key press with no nested if statement, that also did not work... I am new to SFML so this is really hurting my head to figure this out, also I do not mind criticism, please if you see something I could be doing better in terms of sprite movement, let me know! Thanks for your help.

**Below is my player class constructor**

```
#include "Player.h"
    
    
    Player::Player(Texture* texture, Vector2u imageCount, float switchTime, float speed) :
        // initializer list from animation.cpp
        animation(texture, imageCount, switchTime) 
    {
        this->speed = speed;
        row = 0;
    
        body.setSize(Vector2f(100.0f, 150.0f));
        body.setTexture(texture);
        //sets initial position for test sprite sheet
        body.setPosition(550.0f, 900.0f);
    }
    
    Player::~Player()
    {
    }
    
    void Player::Update(float deltaTime)
    {
        Vector2f movement(0.0f, 0.0f);
    
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A))
        {
            //if A is pressed move to the left on the  x axis
            movement.x -= speed * deltaTime;
        }
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D))
        {
            //if D is pressed move to the right on the x axis
            movement.x += speed * deltaTime;
        }
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::W))
        {
            // if W is pressed move up on the y axis
            movement.y += speed * deltaTime;
        }
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::S))
        {
            // if S is pressed move down on the y axis
            movement.y -= speed * deltaTime;
        }
    
        if (movement.x == 0.0f || movement.y == 0.0f)//for idle animation
        {
            row = 0;//idle row for now just using walking until I get idle animation
        }
        else if(movement.x > 0.0f)
        {
            row = 1; //walking to the left animation
        }
        else if (movement.x < 0.0f )
        {
            row = 3; //walking to the right animation
        }
        else if (movement.y > 0.0f)
        {
            row = 0; // walking to stright animation
        }
        else if (movement.y < 0.0f)
        {
            row = 2;// walking back animation
        }
    
        animation.Update(row, deltaTime);
        body.setTextureRect(animation.uvRect);
        body.move(movement);
    
    }
    void Player::Draw(RenderWindow& window)
    {
        window.draw(body);
    }
```

**Below is my player class initialization**

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Animation.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

class Player
{
public:
    Player(Texture* texture, Vector2u imageCount, float switchTime, float speed);
    ~Player();

    void Update(float deltaTime);
    void Draw(RenderWindow& window);

private:
    RectangleShape body;
    Animation animation;
    unsigned int row;
    float speed;

};
```

**Below  Game while loop and the Player function call**

```
    Player player(&playerTexture, Vector2u(9, 4), 0.09f, 100.0);

    //*************************************************************
    //clock & Time
    float deltaTime = 0.0f;

    Clock clock;



    while (window.isOpen())
    {

        deltaTime = clock.restart().asSeconds();

       //*********************************************************
       //Player Input

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape))
        {
            window.close();
        }



       //**********************************************************
       //draws everything

        player.Update(deltaTime);

        window.clear();
        window.draw(spritestartingBG);
        player.Draw(window);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (movement.x == 0.0f || movement.y == 0.0f)` will be true unless moving diagonally-- you probably want the || to be &&.

Similarly, your left/right animations are reversed--you're moving left when movement.x is  < 0.0, not > 0.0.